# Exact meaning of "zizanie"

Tags: vocabulaire

I was speaking with a francophone colleague in English today and he was groping for an English equivalent of the French word "**[zizanie](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/zizanie/83161)**" (to describe a conflict between our respective departments).

He seemed to feel that "zizanie" had a different shade of meaning than "discorde" or "désaccord", but wasn't really able to articulate it.  Can anyone compare and contrast these terms for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meanings are close but these words are not necessarily interchangeable.

***Désaccord*** is the softer of the set. It just means there is some disagreement, usually between two parties but it doesn't imply more. That might be just it. Its opposite is ***accord***, agreement. I can be in *désaccord* about some insignificant thing with a friend, and I can have an *accord* with my worst enemy.

***Discorde*** is stronger, not only the parties disagree but this is creating a conflictual situation. Its opposite is ***concorde*** which is associated with harmony and peace.

***Zizanie*** used to mean not the discord itself, but what is causing it (a bad seed among the good ones). It is nowadays mostly used in the set expression ***semer la zizanie*** (to sow the seeds of discord). While it was a literary word rarely used in the conversation, its popularity was strongly boosted by Astérix's [La Zizanie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Zizanie_(Ast%C3%A9rix)), published in 1970 (in English "[Asterix and the Roman Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Roman_Agent)"), which turned that word from niche to mainstream.

Here are sample sentences showing how these words might differ in context:

You can say: ***Nous sommes en désaccord à propos de ce contrat*** but *Nous sommes en discorde...* would be very odd and *Nous sommes en zizanie* essentially unheard.

On the other hand, we can say both ***Ce qu'il veut, c'est semer la zizanie*** and *[...] **c'est semer la discorde*** but *semer le désaccord*, while not impossible would be dubious.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional meanings, and not even a nuance can be found; what can be read in the Larousse is faithfully repeated in the TLFi and in several other dictionaries.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/zizanie)

[internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/zizanie/)

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zizanie)

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/zizanie)

[The Free Dictionary](https://fr.thefreedictionary.com/zizanie)

[WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/zizanie)

[Le Dictionnaire](https://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition/zizanie)

[Notre Temps](https://dictionnaire.notretemps.com/definitions/zizanie-75411)

[Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/8/consulter/zizanie?page=1)

[Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/zizanie)

Comment: Merci!  My colleague did mention *Astérix and Obelix* in his explanation, so maybe it was less about an exact shade of meaning than it was about referencing a [specific episode](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Zizanie_(Ast%C3%A9rix)) of that comic book.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Selon la Wikipedia il s'agit exactement de zizanie dans cette histoire d'*Astérix et Obélix*, rien de plus, rien de moins (discorde, mésintelligence).